# Virtuemart 2.0.20 show cart not redirect to cart page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using new version of virtuemart 2.0.20. On Product detail page when i click on show cart then it will not rediect to cart page.it is redirecting to some index page. the link it is dispalying on show cart link is 'index.php/component/virtuemart/cart?Itemid=0'. Please tell me how to redirect to cart page.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

put here in your addtocart button

```
      <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo $product->product_name ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
      <input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart" />
      <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product->virtuemart_product_id ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_manufacturer_id" value="<?php echo $product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_category_id[]" value="<?php echo $product->virtuemart_category_id ?>" />
```